# Why is my Anaconda 4.10.3 suggesting upgrade to 2.1.0?

Tags: anaconda, conda

The upgrade message shows that an upgrade to Anaconda Navigator 2.1.0 is available, but my Anaconda is 4.10.3, how is this happening and how can I get rid of the upgrade message?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Navigator isn't versioned in sync with Anaconda, the newest navigator is 2.1.0 and was as far as I can see released in September this year.

Comment: Or, more specifically, Conda != Anaconda Navigator. The OP `conda` version is 4.10.3 and Conda wants to update `anaconda-navigator` to v2.1.0.

Comment: thanks for answering, but how can I check the version of my anaconda navigator?

Comment: From Anaconda Prompt, run `conda list -n base anaconda-navigator`